# How to get Column Values with cell Address From Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am able to read a column from excel using the below code. The code reads the values into a System.Array . And to use that  Sytem.Array object data, i convert it into a List Type.However, for each cell read from the excel...i need its address(more specifically, row no). How can i do that?

```
string sFilePath = "C:\\Mydata.xls";            
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFilePath);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item("PID");
xlApp.Visible = true;

Excel.Range MyColumn = oExcelSheet.UsedRange.Columns[7];
System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)MyColumn.Cells.Value;
List<string> strArray = myvalues.OfType<string>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
```

I dont know if this helps, but when checked in debug mode...the System.Array(i.e myvalues) has cell values with indexes exactly matching with the Row no of the cell which is exactly what i need.

Comment: So... why not use `strArray.IndexOf("whatever string you are looking for")`?

Comment: I could do that, but the problem is some cells are empty in the column. So, when array is converted to list of strings...the indexes with the empty string s are lost. only the cells with the values are stored in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone interested to know the answer...
The code of line below actually skips null values and looses the actual index

```
List<string> strArray = myvalues.OfType<string>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();
```

So, Instead of using the above code...i tried to explicitly loop through the array values and retained the index for every item by adding an 'if null' check and adding items to list

```
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;

List<string> strArray = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    if (myvalues.GetValue(i, 1) == null)
        strArray.Add(" ");   
    else  
       strArray.Add(myvalues.GetValue(i, 1).ToString());  
}
```